# If $\phi \circ \psi_1 = \phi \circ \psi_2$ implies $\psi_1=\psi_2$ for all $\psi_1,\psi_2: T \rightarrow R$ then $\phi$ is a ring monomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $\phi: R \rightarrow S$ be a ring homomorphism. If $\phi \circ \psi_1 = \phi \circ \psi_2$  implies $\psi_1=\psi_2$ for all ring homomorphism $\psi_1,\psi_2: T \rightarrow R$. Prove that $\phi$ is injective.

So I tries to construct a case where $\phi$ is not monomorphism and assume that $\phi \circ \psi_1 = \phi \circ \psi_2$ for all $\psi_1,\psi_2$ but $\psi_1,\psi_2$ fail to be the same. Any hints how to find such case?

Comment: It's monic by definition (because monic is in category theory defined to obey the cancellation law).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are monomorphisms of rings injective?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183337/are-monomorphisms-of-rings-injective)

Comment: @HennoBrandsma In the answer, what does it mean to say $\g_1(X)=x$ and $\g_2(X)=y$?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you pick $T = \mathbb{Z}[x]$, and choose two elements of $R$ that map to the same image via $\phi$?

Comment: Could you explain more explicitly? Thanks

Comment: As in my linked answer, $g_1$ maps $x \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ to $r_1$, and $g_2$ maps to $r_2$, where supposedly $\phi(r_1) = \phi(r_2)$. As it is clear where members of $\mathbb{Z}$ are mapped (in a unitary ring), this totally defines a ring homomorphism (substitution).